# What does "schema" mean?

Tags: terminology

1. In a relational model,

   - a schema is something which specifies the name and data type of each field.
   - The word "schema" is also used in "conceptual schema", "physical schema" and "external schema".

   What do "schema" mean separately in the above two cases? Are they
   related?

   Are they related to the ["schema" in cognitive psychology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schema_(psychology))?
2. Is "schema" used in other areas of computer science, such as
   artificial intelligence, programming languages, ...?
3. What does "schema" mean in computer science besides database?

Thanks!

Comment: The term probably has dozens of uses and meanings. In particular, questions 2 and 3 strike me as too broad, and you should ask only one question per post, anyway. Please focus your question do a reasonable scope!

Answer (score 5):

**1. **What is Schema****-  In a relational database, the schema defines the tables, the fields in each table, and the relationships between fields and tables.

Yes, They are related to these 3 words,  **"conceptual schema"**, **"physical schema"** and **"external schema"**.

- External schema for **user views**
- Conceptual schema **integrates external schemata**
- Internal schema that defines **physical storage structures**

**No, It has no relation with "schema" in cognitive psychology**

**2. Yes**, Schema used in other area also like in-

**Programming & Algorithms** -[XML Schema](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_schema) , [Schema (genetic algorithms)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schema_%28genetic_algorithms%29) 
**Science**- [Body Schema](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Body_schema), [Image Schema](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_schema) 
**Mathematics**- [Axiom Schema](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_schema) (related to Mathematical Logic)

**3.**  Refer above point 1 & 2